# Basics of Java - Cannot convert from void to String

Tags: java

Hello Guys i'm tring to undestand how Java works and i don't know what to do in order to solve this problem.  I have this class:

```java
public class Algoritmo {

    public static void algoritmofigo() {

        double y = 4.5454;
        int g = 45;
        int  po = 567;
        int num = 54;
        char lett = 'f';

        if (y == 4) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        } else if (g == 400) {
            System.out.println(num);
        } else {
            System.out.println(g + po);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm tring to use it in a way like this:

```java
Algoritmo algo = new Algoritmo();
String rrr = algo.algoritmofigo();
System.out.println(dog);
```

That's my first day of Java and i can't figure out how to move.

The Error says: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String.

I Just would like to know what's the mistake is and how to fix it. Thanks you!

Comment: Your method does not return anything but just prints output. You try to assign the returned value to a `String`. :boom:

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change void to String and instead of printing inside your function you have to return the String

System.out.println("Hello"); --> return "Hello"

Explanation: void stands for no return from Function. If you want to give something back from the function you need to set there the type of return. Like you want to get a String than you have to return one. But be carefule, sometimes there are problems in java like if you return an integer number and expect an String than you have to convert the number to String. But there are already given Methods for that

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic as given below

```
public static String algoritmofigo() {

    double y = 4.5454;
    int g = 45;
    int  po = 567;
    int num = 54;
    char lett = 'f';

    if (y == 4) {
        return "Hello";

    } else if ( g == 400) {
        return Integer.toString(num);

    } else {
        return Integer.toString(g + po);
    }
}
```

And call is like that as its a static method

```
String rrr = Algoritmo.algoritmofigo();
System.out.println(dog);
```